# Literature on the reals or their gaps in $L[0^\sharp]$?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, textbook-recommendation, inner-model-theory

I'm doing my Bachelor's Thesis on the continuum in $L$ and $L[0^\sharp]$.

In $L$ I study the gaps without new reals (sets of natural numbers) in the hierarchy, as presented in *[Gaps in the constructible universe, Marek and Srebrny, 1973](https://zbmath.org/?q=Gaps%20in%20the%20constructible%20universe%2C%20Marek%20and%20Srebrny)*. Of course, the issue is deeply linked to the fine structure of $L$, as studied in [*The fine structure of the constructible hierarchy, Jensen, 1972*](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0257.02035).
I've also looked into some pathological properties of the continuum in $L$, such as the existence of a $∆_2^1$ nonmeasurable set.

I haven't found much literature on any of these two topics regarding $L[0^\sharp]$. Certainly, many of the gap results are easily generalizable to $L[a]$, but I'd like to know whether anyone has studied further how the information codified in $0^\sharp$ might affect the hierarchy, or spawn benign or pathological properties.

I have found some talk of $L[0^\sharp]$ in Friedman's [Fine structure and class forcing](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0954.03045), but they don't dwell on these details and the book is also highly advanced.

Thanks in advance :)